# Is it possible to use the increase() function without a label in PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to do something like this:

```
increase without (filename) (rejected_files_total[10h])
```

But I am getting the next error:

> Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': 1:10: parse error: unexpected

Can "without" and "by" be used only on Aggregation operators? If so is there any other way to get the effect of without also in an increase function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want obtaining the summary increase over multiple time series groups without `filename` label, then try the following query:

```
sum(increase(rejected_files_total[10h])) without (filename)
```

It uses [sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function for aggregating [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) results over multiple metrics with the name `rejected_files_total`.